# Options for pml command with Drush 10

Tags: drush

I just install a Drupal 9.2 site and Drush 10 to manage it.
Usually I use Drush 9 and Drupal 8.9.

It appear option for pml command seem not to work in Drush 10 as it do in Drush 9.
Example:

```
 drush @pfdevd9pf pml --filter=rss
  The "--filter" option does not exist.

drush @pfdevd9pf pml | grep "rss"
 RRSSB  Ridiculously Responsive Social Share Buttons (rrssb)   Disabled   8.x-2.3
```

This is a weird thing, then I do a module activation:

```
 drush @pfdevd9pf en -y rrssb
 [success] Successfully enabled: rrssb
```

But pml still give the same info about module version:

```
  RRSSB   Ridiculously Responsive Social Share Buttons (rrssb)   Enabled    8.x-2.3
```

I use D8 website too on this server, but installations are distincts. If someone know about this, and why pml doesn't use the option ?

Thanks

EDIt: about the version number for module, as @4k4 say, it depends on the module developpment. This is another example for D9:

```
  Other    Backup and Migrate (backup_migrate) Disabled   5.0.1
```

EDIt2: multiple drush version can be an issue, because in my .bash_profile I get:
Drush 8 globally installed

```
alias drush='$HOME/bin/composer/composer.phar/vendor/drush/drush/drush'
```

then:

```
#Création d'un alias pour Drush 9 pour usage global
alias drush9='$HOME/www/pfdev/multid8/vendor/drush/drush/drush'

#Création d'un alias pour Drush 10 pour usage global
alias drush10='$HOME/www/pfdev/multid9/recommended-project/vendor/drush/drush/drush'

#PATH ajouté manuellement suite retour commande Drush
#export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/www/pfdev/multid8/vendor/drush/drush/drush"

    # Switch drush versions for session. Changer de version pour la session
    alias d8='export PATH=$HOME/bin/drush:$PATH'
    alias d9='export PATH=$HOME/www/pfdev/multid8/vendor/bin:$PATH'
    alias d10='export PATH=$HOME/www/pfdev/multid9/recommended-project/vendor/bin:$PATH'
```

but I use drush as alias, never d9 or d10.In addition, I need to be on the ~/ to use alias...created for D8. So I think I need to change my Drush 8 install, and remove it globally. isn't it ?

Comment: The filter option does work in Drush 10, just tested it. But this doesn't really matter because you can just use grep as you've demonstrated. But how is this connected with the other things you are doing?

Comment: _But pml still give the same info about module version:_ That's the expected result, enabling a module does not alter its version.

Comment: @4k4 Are you sure? Output from `drush pml --help` doesn't show a `filter` option and I get the same error message using Drush 10.6.1 (_The "--filter" option does not exist._)

Comment: @4k4 is it normal that the module version 8.x is the same for D8 or D9 website ?

Comment: Yes, modules now can support two Drupal versions at the same time. The semantic versioning has changed and doesn't contain the core version anymore. Most modules move for example from 8.x-2.3 to 3.0.x when publishing a new release. But they don't need to, they can still use the old version in Drupal 9.

Comment: @Clive, interesting, I have the same `drush version`: Drush version : 10.6.1

Comment: @Clive yes I know that but I was surprised to see the same version number for D8 and D9 modules. As 4k4 say, it is the normal way. But my question is about the filter option, by the way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question is about the filter option, by the way

The filter option is available in the current Drush version. In general
https://www.drush.org/latest/output-formats-filters/#output-filters and for this drush command https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/pm_list/.

If not, then you are probably running an older Drush version installed somewhere on your computer. To be sure run Drush locally from the root folder of your Drupal site:

```
composer require drush/drush
vendor/bin/drush pml --filter=block
```

This should display the two core modules and one or two others.

Comment: Yes, probably. Best practice is to run drush like in my answer. If you don't want to specify vendor/bin/drush each time see https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher